# regexp for parsing xml to array

Tags: php, regex

pls. I have problem using regexp expresion in the following php function:

```
$xml1 = "<arg1>
        <S113-03>1</S113-03>
        <S184-06>1</S184-06>
    </arg1>";

$xml2 = "<arg1>
        <P055>1</P055>
        <P096>1</P096>
    </arg1>";

function xml2array($xml) {
     $xmlArray = array();
     $regexp = "/<(\w+)\s*([^\/>]*)\s*(?:\/>|>(.*)<\/\s*\\1\s*>)/s";
     preg_match_all($regexp, $xml, $elements);

     foreach ($elements[1] as $ie => $element) {
         if (preg_match($regexp, $elements[3][$ie]))
             $xmlArray[$element] = xml2array($elements[3][$ie]);
         else {
             $xmlArray[$element] = trim($elements[3][$ie]);
         }
     }
return $xmlArray;
}

$array = xml2array($xml1);
echo print_r($array, true);
```

while $xml2 gives me result (it is OK):

```
Array
(
    [arg1] => Array
        (
            [P055] => 1
            [P096] => 1
        )

)
```

while $xml1 gives me result (wrong):

```
Array
(
    [arg1] => <S113-03>1</S113-03>
            <S184-06>1</S184-06>
)
```

I believe the problem is in regexp, but its content seems to be chinesse tea for me

Comment: Don't use regex. There are answers giving you better options... which are [plentiful](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

Comment: Thanks to all. In fact the function is a part of a stock import interface in Magento and I was not sure to replace the original regexp with SimpleXMLElement because I do not understand the reason of using regexp there. anyway thanks for both alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this fix, note the updated `(\w+)` that is now `([\w-]+)`:

```
$regexp = "/<([\w-]+)\s*([^\/>]*)\s*(?:\/>|>(.*)<\/\s*\\1\s*>)/s";
```

The result is

```
Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    [arg1] => Array                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            [S113-03] => 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            [S184-06] => 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

)
```

Here is the [sample code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMc3BraVY3djJNRG8).

Comment: @Downvoter: What is wrong with the regex fix? When you downvote a working solution, you'll end up with no rep at all sooner or later.

Comment: I understand people do not like regex approach when they see rich texts, but I just suggest a fix to the current code. I am not imposing a regex solution to anyone.

Answer (score 4):

You know Chuck Norris?

> Chuck Norris can parse HTML with RegExp.

Anyway here with go without RegExp:

[Demo](https://ideone.com/PxlAFo)

```
<?php

$xml1 = "<arg1>
        <S113-03>1</S113-03>
        <S184-06>1</S184-06>
    </arg1>";

$xml2 = "<arg1>
        <P055>1</P055>
        <P096>1</P096>
    </arg1>";

function xml2array($xmlString)
{
    $xml   = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    return json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), TRUE);
}

var_dump(xml2array($xml1));
var_dump(xml2array($xml2));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["S113-03"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["S184-06"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  ["P055"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["P096"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: agreed. chuck norris can parse html/xml with regex, childs play

Comment: the point being, *only* chuck norris can pull it off. *Everyone else* should stay well away from regexp for xml/html parsing

Comment: @tucuxi: I doubt Chuck Norris understands the word "tag". I can use regexes, I can (?:read|write) them. If I need to parse out a simple .?(?=ML) string from a known source, I will go for it!

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier and quicker (more memory-wise) to use [PHP SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) functionality.

```
$xml1 = "<arg1>
        <S113-03>1</S113-03>
        <S184-06>2</S184-06>
    </arg1>";

$xml2 = "<arg1>
        <P055>3</P055>
        <P096>4</P096>
    </arg1>";

var_dump(new \SimpleXMLElement($xml1));
var_dump(new \SimpleXMLElement($xml2));
```

dumps:

```
php test.php
class SimpleXMLElement#1 (2) {
  public $S113-03 =>
  string(1) "1"
  public $S184-06 =>
  string(1) "2"
}
class SimpleXMLElement#1 (2) {
  public $P055 =>
  string(1) "3"
  public $P096 =>
  string(1) "4"
}
```